# Windows Phone 8.1 SignalR client terminate the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating an application that uses SignalR for chatting purposes.
when the user close the App, I want to terminate the connection so he/she can no longer be online.
but it seems it takes like 3-10 seconds to terminate the connection, which is something I dont want.

I was searching about background tasks in WP8.1, but I have a feeling its not the right approach.

is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Background tasks are certainly not the way to go. What happens if you just send the request for disconnect in a fire and forget manner?

Comment: @Stilgar, actually didn't try it, will it run after the application is closed ?

Comment: No but if you delay for just a second it should be enough to send the information about the disconnect which would inform the server that the user is no longer in the chat. The user will not receive the acknowledgement but who cares? BTW all this is how I imagine things work. I have not looked at the SignalR source code.

Of course you should also handle timeout disconnects anyway so even if the operation fails the user will be disconnected just not immediately.

Comment: there is no acknowledgement about the disconnect process, but I dont want any delay on closing.
according to what I've read yesterday, you can not control the disconnect timeout in signalR, it will supported in the next version I guess.
other than that, everything else is handled.

Comment: Delay the closing by a very small amount. As far as I remember the app should go off screen anyway.

Comment: its not the proper approach for me.
but thank you for helping :D